# JavaFX TextField causes NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx, textfield

I am using a Button with an event to control the input of a user, but I am having trouble checking whether or not the TextField is empty.
The TextField and Button are declared before the button event, like

```
TextField svar = new TextField();
Button submitB = new Button("submit");
```

This is my code:

```
submitB.setOnAction((event) -> {

        if (svar.getText().equals(null) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("No input!");
        }

        if (svar.getText().subSequence(0, 1).toString().toLowerCase().equals(animals.get(pic).getName().subSequence(0, 1).toString().toLowerCase())) {
            primaryStage.setTitle("RÄTT!");
            bild.setImage(new Image(animals.get(pic+=1).getImgsrc()));
            svar.setText(null);
            svar.requestFocus();
        }
        else 
        {
            primaryStage.setTitle("FEL!");
            svar.setText(null);
            svar.requestFocus();
        }

    });
```

This piece of the code above is what in my mind should handle a situation where the TextField is empty:

```
        if (svar.getText().equals(null) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("No input!");
        }
```

However I am still getting a NullPointerException no matter what. I've tried some different solutions which have all failed and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: and simply using svar.getText().isEmpty() throws a NullPointerException?

Comment: Yes, this method also throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling equals to check for null, you should use "==" like:

```
 if (svar.getText() == null) {
```

Reason you get NPE (NullPointerException) is, since as you say `svar.getText()` is null, you are trying to call equals on null and a reason for NPE.

Comment: This worked. I am pretty new to java and I've been told to stay away from '==' and Strings, but when I think about it this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it, is not check for Null, but to check for a empty String:

```
if (svar.getText().equals("") {
    primaryStage.setTitle("No input!");
}
```

Some prefer:

```
if ("".equals(svar.getText() {
    primaryStage.setTitle("No input!");
}
```